# Docker load in docker compose yaml

Tags: docker

I want to use a docker image which is stored in an image tar file in docker-compose.

There is "docker load" command to load a image from an image tar file in command line usage.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/

Is it possible to use the docker load command in a docker-compose yaml file?

Comment: The `docker-compose` command has no ability to load an image from a tar archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker-compose command has no ability to load an image from a tar archive

but you can save docker image from another host with command `docker save` and create a `tar` file , and use them on your host with `docker load`